# Problems with recieving letter input in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, keydown

For a game i'm coding, there's one part during the main menu where you're required to press 'P' to play.  I started using this code:

```
import pygame, sys, time
DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((1023, 647))
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
mainscreendisplayimg = pygame.image.load('mainScreen.png')
def mainscreen(x, y):
     DISPLAY.blit(mainscreendisplayimg, (x, y))
mainscreen(1, 1)
pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
while active:
     ...
     if pressed[pygame.K_p]:
          print 'Done'
     pygame.display.update()
     clock.tick(15)
```

What I would think would happen is it would display the main image, which gives you instructions to press p, and then it would print 'Done' (this will be replaced with more code at a later date).  However, whenever I execute the program, the image will load but nothing will happen when I press p.

I also tried using the keydown method, but there was no change.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you set active = True somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured this out on my own thanks for the help anyway!
It turns out that I was using keydown incorrectly and accidentally had some syntax errors making it malfunction.

For reference and to help others, here's the updated code:

```
active = true
while active:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
               if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    print 'Done'
```

Thanks for those who tried to help, sorry I wasted your time